# Calendar not giving correct date

Tags: java

I'll be using MM/dd/yyyy format
Below code should give me "07/01/2017" but instead its giving me "06/30/2017" but if i uncomment //cal.getTime(); i'm getting "07/01/2017"

can someone explain this behaviour.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date("04/02/2017");
    cal.setTime(date);
    System.out.println(date);
    Calendar nQtStartDate = new GregorianCalendar(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
             Calendar.JUNE, 30);
    cal = nQtStartDate;
    //cal.getTime();

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);


    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getTime()` method internally update the time and change the state of variable `isTimeSet` (which, for what I see reading the source code, makes the class not thread safe).

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
    if (!isTimeSet) {
        updateTime();
    }
    return time;
}
```

On the other hand the statement `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY)` reset the state of internal time (changing the variable `isTimeSet` to false).

The state of variable `isTimeSet` is `true` if the value of internal `time` is valid.

Just to summarise: do not change the calendar configuration (i.e. set the day of week) after have called the `getTime()` method because this will reset the internal status of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Javadocs for `Calendar` explain this:

"Any field values set in a `Calendar` will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of the calendar fields. Calling the `get`, `getTimeInMillis`, `getTime`, `add` and `roll` involves such calculation."

Comment: Thank you!! That helped.. but nQtStartDate  is a new object with time and it is not getting changed, If you do the same operation with it, It still won't give me correct date.

Comment: "but"? It should be obvious that the quoted passage applies to that situation. And it is changed because you set `cal = nQtStartDate;`.